# Error while making a subscription on webhooks on facebook app developer platform

Tags: facebook, bots, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I am not able to make webhooks new page subscription its giving me an error in the callback url saying "(The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value = '736926330', received=')", i am not having a domain name as same as my app name.

Comment: What is unclear? Your script does not return the challenge value as expected. Only you can find out why - so do some debugging.

Comment: i did some debugging like changing the url path to my blogspot,gmail,wordpess urls buts its like giving the same error like its not able to match with my challenge. @CBroe

Comment: What, why are you randomly changing URLs? You should know under which address your script resides, no?

Comment: i haven't made any scripts for this as its not a live project thought that webhooks don't need servers or backed scripts or a live website to work. Was trying to learn and make facebook messenger bot feature as an private page user. @CBroe Should i take it live to make it work???

Comment: _“thought that webhooks don't need servers or backed scripts or a live website to work”_ – you thought wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server the supports https and script code running on it to authenticate the subscription.

[Facebook Messenger Platform Developers Complete Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation)